# Config questions

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to know how to send a player a list of their shops when they type `/shoplist`. Also, I would like to know how to change the name of a shop depending on what they type so if they use `/shopname Shop1 Pie` it would change the name of Shop1 to pie. Or if they do not have a shop called shop1 then it would say a message if they don't have any shops when they make a shop then it builds a new section in the config for them.

Here is my main file:

```
public class Shops extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

  public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("************************");
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("*Shops Plugin Enabled  *");
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("*Shops by McMatt       *");
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("************************");
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Signs(), this);
    getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
    saveConfig();


  }

  public void onDisable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("************************");
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("*Shops Plugin Disabled *");
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("*Shops by McMatt       *");
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("************************");

  }

  public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("shops")) {
      if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage("You must be a player to run this command");
        return true;
      }

      Player player = (Player) sender;


      if (!player.hasPermission("shops.shops")) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You do not have to permission (shops.shops)");
        return true;


      } else {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Shops:");
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "---" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Commands" + ChatColor.RED + "---");
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "/shops" + ChatColor.GREEN + " Displays this");
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "/shopslist" + ChatColor.GREEN + " Used to list shops");
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "---" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Signs" + "---");
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "First line:" + ChatColor.GREEN + " [shop]");
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "Second line:" + ChatColor.GREEN + " {Open or Closed}");

      }
    }
    return true;
  }



  public boolean onCommand1(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("shopslist")) {
      sender.sendMessage("Getting shops info!");
      sender.sendMessage(getConfig().getString("" + sender.getName()));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's my listener file

```
public class Signs implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent e) {
        if (e.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("[shop]")) {
            Block attached = e.getBlock().getRelative(0, -1, 0);
            String name = e.getPlayer().getDisplayName();
            if (!(attached.getType() == Material.CHEST))
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please place the shop on a chest!");
            else {
                if (!e.getPlayer().hasPermission("shops.create"))
                    e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don't have permission to create a shop! (shops.create)");
                else {
                    if (!Arrays.asList("open", "closed").contains(e.getLine(1).toLowerCase())) {
                        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must specify if the shop is open or closed on the second line!");
                    } else {
                        boolean closed = true;
                        if ("open".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getLine(1))) {
                            closed = false;
                        }

                        String lineThree = closed ? "§cClosed" : "§aOpen";
                        e.setLine(3, lineThree);
                        e.setLine(0, "§9[Shop]");
                        e.setLine(1, "§b" + name + "'s");
                        e.setLine(2, "§bShop");
                        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Shop Created!");
                        e.getPlayer().playSound(e.getPlayer().getLocation(), Sound.LEVEL_UP, 10, 10);
                        //if(getConfig().equals(null)){
                            //int shopAmount = 0;
                            //shopAmount = shopAmount + 1;
                            //getConfig().createSection(name);
                            //getConfig().addDefault(name + ":.Shops:", "Shop" + shopAmount);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            Block b = e.getClickedBlock();
            Material m = b.getType();
            if (!(m == Material.SIGN_POST)) {
                return;
            } else {
                Sign sign = (Sign) e.getClickedBlock().getState();
                if ((sign.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("§9[Shop]"))) {
                    if ((sign.getLine(3).equalsIgnoreCase("§aOpen"))) {
                        p.sendMessage("I opened the shop!");
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my configuration file

> McMatt:
>       - Shop1

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `List<String>` of all of the player's shops by using

```
config.getStringList(playerName);
```

So, for example, if your config looked like this:

```
McMatt:
    - "Shop1"
    - "Awesome Shop"
jojodmo:
    - "Jojo Shop"
```

using

```
config.getStringList("McMatt");
```

Would return a `List<String>` containing the strings *Shop1* and *Awesome Shop*.

Also, to avoid a `NullPointerException`, you should make sure the player has shops in the config by using

```
if(config.contains(playerName))
```

and send the player a message telling them that they have no shops.

So, your code could look something like this:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("shops")){
        //your code
        if(sender instanceof Player){
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            String name = player.getName();

            if(config.contains(name)){
                List<String> shops = config.getStringList(name);

                for(String shop : shops){
                     //do something with the shop       
                }
            }
            else{
                //the user has no shops
            }
        }
        //...
    }
}
```